# Unable to deploy a preview channel on PR with firebase github actions

Tags: firebase, next.js, github-actions, firebase-hosting, turborepo

I have a monorepo (turbo) and a nextjs app. I changed the yml file, which is generated from firebase, but after all the checks were done in the actions and followed the link I got the following message from firebase [Page Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wCis.png):

The firebase.json:

```
{
"firestore": {
    "rules": "firebase/firestore/firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firebase/firestore/firestore.indexes.json"
},
"functions": {
    "source": "firebase/functions"
},
"hosting": {
    "public": "apps/onboarding/out",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
},
"storage": {
    "rules": "firebase/cloud-storage/storage.rules"
},
```

And here is the .yml file:

```
name: Build and deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
on: pull_request

env:
    NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CONFIG: '${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CONFIG }}'
    NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT: development

jobs:
    install-deps:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            ## Checkout current branch
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

              ## Setup node
            - name: Use Node.js 16.x
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: 16.x

              ## Cache node modules
            - name: Cache node modules
              id: cache-npm
              uses: actions/cache@v3
              env:
                  cache-name: cache-node-modules
              with:
                  path: node_modules
                  key: v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-

            ## Install dependencies
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: |
                  npm ci

    lint:
        needs: install-deps
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            ## Checkout current branch
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

              ## Setup node
            - name: Use Node.js 16.x
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: 16.x

              ## Cache node modules
            - name: Cache node modules
              id: cache-npm
              uses: actions/cache@v3
              env:
                  cache-name: cache-node-modules
              with:
                  path: node_modules
                  key: v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-

            ## Run lint
            - name: Run lint
              run: |
                  npm run lint

    test:
        needs: install-deps
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            ## Checkout current branch
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

              ## Setup node
            - name: Use Node.js 16.x
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: 16.x

              ## Cache node modules
            - name: Cache node modules
              id: cache-npm
              uses: actions/cache@v3
              env:
                  cache-name: cache-node-modules
              with:
                  path: node_modules
                  key: v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-

            ## Run test
            - name: Run test
              run: |
                  npm run test

    build:
        needs: install-deps
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            ## Checkout current branch
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

              ## Setup node
            - name: Use Node.js 16.x
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: 16.x

              ## Cache node modules
            - name: Cache node modules
              id: cache-npm
              uses: actions/cache@v3
              env:
                  cache-name: cache-node-modules
              with:
                  path: node_modules
                  key: v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-

            ## Build
            - name: Build
              run: |
                  npm run build

            ## Store artifacts for deployment in case of push in the main
            - name: Archive onboarding/out artifacts
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
              with:
                  name: preview-build-onboarding
                  path: apps/onboarding/out/**

            - name: Archive function/lib artifacts
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
              with:
                  name: preview-build-functions
                  path: firebase/functions/lib/**
    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        env:
            CI_FIREBASE_MESSAGE: ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }} - ${{ github.event.head_commit.url }}/checks

        needs: [build, install-deps, lint, test]
        steps:
            ## Checkout current branch
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

            ## Setup node
            - name: Use Node.js 16.x
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: 16.x

            ## Cache node modules
            - name: Cache node modules
              id: cache-npm
              uses: actions/cache@v3
              env:
                  cache-name: cache-node-modules
              with:
                  path: node_modules
                  key: v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-build-
                      v1-${{ runner.os }}-

            - name: Download onboarding/out artifacts
              uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
              with:
                  name: preview-build-onboarding
                  path: apps/onboarding/out/**

            - name: Download function/lib artifacts
              uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
              with:
                  name: preview-build-functions
                  path: firebase/functions/lib/**

            - name: Deploy Preview
              uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
              with:
                  repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
                  firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_******** }}'
                  projectId: ********
```

I have absolutely no clue why it is failing at the moment, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please improve your question by (1) reviewing the formatting, and (2) create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).